# Why does my docker processes keep restarting on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, deluge

I'm attempting to use deluge on my Raspberry Pi.

I've followed the guide as per: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/deluge

I've created a `docker-compose.yml` file which consists of the following:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  deluge:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest
    container_name: deluge
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - DELUGE_LOGLEVEL=error #optional
    volumes:
      - /path/to/deluge/config:/config
      - /path/to/your/downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 8112:8112
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I can run the above using the command `docker compose up -d`

Once the service is running I check it using `docker ps` which shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS                           PORTS     NAMES
2524b4bb191b   lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest   "/init"   5 minutes ago   Restarting (111) 2 seconds ago             deluge
```

When running `docker ps` sometimes it shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                                                                                              NAMES
2524b4bb191b   lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest   "/init"   5 minutes ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:6881->6881/tcp, :::6881->6881/tcp, 58846/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8112->8112/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6881->6881/udp, :::8112->8112/tcp, :::6881->6881/udp, 58946/tcp, 58946/udp   deluge
```

But, soon after it shows the following again:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS     NAMES
2524b4bb191b   lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest   "/init"   7 minutes ago   Restarting (111) 55 seconds ago             deluge
```

Hence I cannot remote into it via a browser.

Any ideas anybody? I'm pulling my hair out!!!

Comment: Does the container have any logs (`docker logs`)? What's the status section say in an inspect (`docker inspect`)?

Comment: `docker logs deluge` shows the following: ```s6-linux-init-hpr: fatal: unable to reboot(): Operation not permitted
s6-svscan: warning: unable to iopause: Operation not permitted
s6-svscan: warning: executing into .s6-svscan/crash
s6-svscan crashed. Killing everything and exiting.
s6-linux-init-hpr: fatal: unable to reboot(): Operation not permitted```

Comment: `/path/to/deluge/config` I am assuming you are using proper folders with correct permissions, is that right?

Comment: ```pi@Pi4:/path/to/deluge/config $ pwd
/path/to/deluge/config``` The folder gets created the moment the docker script is run

Comment: There was clearly a corruption in my docker. I was about to "nuke" my Pi and re-image it but decided to following this YouTube video verbatim before doing so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ahV7DD_Oxk&t=310s This fixed the issue and now deluge is always up in docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is error that occurs when running older versions (<2.5) of libseccomp2 with Docker.

The "answered" Youtube link likely resolved this for you through the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

These apps all use Alpine Linux as a common base image. However, Alpine made a move that caused some chaos for us. Their Alpine 3.13 variant is not compatible with Raspberry Pi 4 devices IF:

1. You are running a version of Docker prior to 19.04 (which is currently the case for stock Raspbian Repositories which has version 18 as the latest.
2. You are running an outdated libseccomp2 library.

Likely not recommended, although you could potentially install libseccomp2 backports directly and you may need to update dock.io -
`sudo apt install libseccomp2 -t buster-backports`
Source: https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/

Similar notes of libseccomp2 impacting PiHole:
https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/blob/b18d9bd419fb76f1ad6a6df3a035204884837547/README.md#upgrade-notes